# Правильно ли использовать один файл CSS для нескольких страниц сайта?

Tags: html, css

Допустим, я сверстал главную страничку интернет-магазина, и задал ей фон через файл style.css:

```
body {
    background: #000000 url('../img/background_1.jpg') no-repeat 3px 50%;
}
```

Теперь мне необходимо сверстать страничку "прайс-лист" этого же магазина, но там я уже хочу, чтобы фоном был файл "background_2.jpg". Но если я использую для прайс-листа ссылку на этот же файл style.css, то там уже задано правило для тега body. Как обычно поступают в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Обычно разделяют стили на несколько файлов по логике. Общее - подключается везде, частное - на конкретной страничке.

Comment: Писать это в разные `css` файлы или же заключить фон страницы в `head` в `<style>...</style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно, CSS и придуман для того что бы сайт привести к единому стилю. Так что это норма. А вашем случае с ситуацией с тегом BODY и его персонализацией (к остальным можно относится так же) вы можете применять классы, пример с DIV тегом:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.page1 {
  background-image: url('https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/WsxUquz/4k-animation-abstract-motion-background-shine-light-bokeh-particles-loop_41kyra_o__S0000.jpg');
}

.page2 {
  background-image: url('http://i14.beon.ru/29/60/246029/80/12763180/26189495_glyamur_.jpeg');
}
```

```html
<div class="page1">text</div>
<div class="page2">text</div>
```

Comment: То есть Вы предлагаете добавить тегу body какой-то класс специально для этой цели?

Comment: @Никита, и это будет правильнее, нежели там выше советуют умники! Не корректно в каждом html писать стили в head. Там пишутся обычно исключительные стили, которые могут касаться плагина, но не фона, даже если это body. Можете разделять Ваши css файлы, но желательно использовать сборщик (например gulp) чтобы на выходе (в релизе) уже было не более 2-х файлов стилей.